# How can I write Windows batch file command with loop and % operator?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I want to write the following code in a batch file. How can I do that?

```c
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   rem = i % 10;
   if(rem == 0)
   {
     // ECHO something
   }
   else
   {
     ECHO i         
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's rather complicated, because of the way [variable expansion in loops works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12118810/4751173) in batch files. Batch files do have their own `for` construct; no need to mess around with [`goto`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful). `%%` is the modulo operator in batch files, as `%` is reserved for expansion of variables.

This code works for me:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (0,1,99) do (
  set /a remainder = %%i %% 10
  if !remainder! == 0 (
    echo something
  ) else (
    echo %%i
  )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Nitpicking `i<100` means max 99 so it should be `for /l %%i in (0,1,99) do (`

Comment: The for loop can be comblned with a Call to a subroutine to avoid the delayed Expansion difficulties

Answer (score 2):

Modulo can be done with [`set /a`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html). Loops can be done with [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html), just like how you convert those `for` loops into `goto` in C

```bat
@echo off
set "i=0"
:loop
if %i% equ 100 goto :endfor
set /a "mod=i %% 10"
if %mod% equ 0 (
    echo something %mod%
) else (
    echo %i%
)
set /a "i+=1"
goto :loop
:endfor
```

Notice that `rem` is a command for starting a comment so I suggest avoiding it as a variable name

The loop can be made simpler with [`for /l`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) but now you have to [enable delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) because the whole body of `for` is parsed at once

Comment: The for loop can be comblned with a Call to a subroutine to avoid the delayed Expansion difficulties